# ol within ul and make certain list items extend to the width of parent element

Tags: css, html-lists

I am kind of new to css and trying to create a layout that presents a list of books. Therefore I want to display a cover image (represented by a fixed width div in the fiddle) at the left side of a two column layout. To the right of the cover I want to present information about the book: The title and an ordered list which has property-value items.

These items should fill the remaining part of the width. The property and its corresponding value should be placed on the same line.

One of the property value items also contains a button, which is just represented by a span here. The button should be placed in the same line right after the property.

I have run into several problems, which I couldn't sort out so far:

- The property list is not formatted correctly. I guess that is because I haven't been able to configure the containing list item to extend to the full width. In the end a property value item should be displayed on the same line.
- The Title is underlined and I would like to see that underline extend to the full width of the body. Currently it is truncated and I haven't been able to figure out a way to make that happen.

I have created a fiddle, which should show the problems: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xeb7/3/

This is my basic html structure:

```
<body>
    <ul class="book">
        <li>
            <div class="cover"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="bookdetail">
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <ol class="attributes">
                <li>
                    <span class="property">property <span>btn</span></span>
                    <span class="value">value</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <span class="property">property</span>
                    <span class="value">value</span>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: what is your second problem `The Title is underlined and I..` do you want to expand right division to entire body width?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to have the line extended beyond the text... until it reaches the right end of the body

Comment: Will the width of `.book` and `.cover` remain constant?

Comment: .cover is fixed width. .book depends on the body width minus cover and padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Your HTML is somewhat more complicated than necessary and makes unorthodox use of list elements for things that aren't really lists.  Simplifying it would make styling the page easier.  I have done so in this jsFiddle, where I think your problems have been taken care of by absolutely positioning `.cover` and adding appropriate padding to `.bookdetails`: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xeb7/10/.  (**Edit**: new jsfiddle reflects comments)

**Long Answer**

As much as possible, the HTML tags you use should be *semantically-related* to the content they represent.  So use `ul` or `ol` for lists of things, use `img` for images, and use heading tags (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) for headings.  There's no need to use `table`s here (which are generally frowned upon for layout since they violate this semantic logic).  Here I've preserved your structure and CSS classes but used more logical tags:

```
    <div class="book">
        <img class="cover" src="" alt="Book Title Here" />
        <div class="bookdetail">
            <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
            <ol class="attributes">
                <li>
                    <span class="property">property</span> <!-- this span wasn't closed before! -->
                    <span class="button">btn</span></span>
                    <span class="value">value</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="property">property</span>
                    <span class="value">value</span>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div><!-- /.bookdetail -->
    </div><!-- /.book -->
```

Once the HTML has been cleaned up you can more easily make the necessary CSS changes.  Your main issue is getting `.bookdetail` in the right place.  It's hard at the moment because you're trying to balance a fixed-width element (`.cover`) with a variable-width element (`.bookdetail`) that you want to take up the whole of its container - except for the fixed-width element.

This can be solved fairly easily by absolutely positioning `.cover`, so it no longer has any effect on the positioning of other elements in `.book`.  Then you can just set the padding of .bookdetail to `0 0 0 140px` - which is automatically relative to the most recent parent element with a specified position, which I've made `.book`.  So `.bookdetail` expands to fill `book` like you want, but the right padding (or margin, if you prefer) means that it doesn't overlap with the cover image.

I've also made a few other CSS changes, visible in the jsFiddle, to make .title display better and to accommodate my HTML changes, but they're not directly relevant to solving your main issue so I'll leave them there.

Comment: That looks pretty good... but why are all the values moved to the right? Is it possible to specify margin-left: 41%; and have them moved 41% to the right in relation to the parent element?

Comment: I understand that. However, your solution specifies margin-left: 41%; but it looks more like 90%. Is the margin relative to the size of the left element?

Comment: I see the issue - the reason for that is that `.property` also had `width:40%`, which is pushing out the `value` elements.  I'll fix it in my code.

Comment: I've taken away `.property`'s width now - but otherwise all the code for those `<span>` tags are as they were in your original code, and you should feel free to modify them to get the positioning you want.

Comment: Here is my take on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xeb7/11/ That seems to work fine for me. Except when the width of the page gets too small, which leads to some pretty ugly results.

Comment: I think most flexible layouts break down at extremely small sizes; if you want it to adapt to them it's probably best to have some special style rules for narrow pages rather than trying to have one rule for all widths.  Also, thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your layout accordingly using `div` and `tables`

```
<div class="leftColumn">

    </div>

    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div class="header">
            Title
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr><td>Property1<td><td>Value</td>
                <tr><td>Property2<td><td>Value</td>
                <tr><td>Property3<td><td>Value</td>
            <div>
 </div>
```

and css

```
.leftColumn
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:250px;
    background-color:red;
}
.rightColumn
{
    float:right;
    width:70%;
    height:250px;
    background-color:green;
}
.header
{
    font-size:25px;
    padding:15px;
    height:30px;
    verticle-align:middle;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;    
}
```

have a [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/GqdBs/)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to make it work that way on my project. Any reasons why you did not use list items? What is best practice in that case? Is it possible to not specify a height as there probably might be more property-value items?

Comment: I certainly will. I had a little trouble with your fiddle, as I do not want to scale the cover image in the left column. This is what I could come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/GqdBs/1/ Any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing width attribute for dimensions but not sure if this is how you want to see it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/7Xeb7/4/

I added width: 100% on you **bookdetail** class

```
.bookdetail {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not. I want the details of the book to the right of the cover image. In your example the details are below the cover. Secondly the value label should be placed at 40% of the parent element's width. The values are very far on the right in your example. Thanks though.